# Pegar valor de um html Windows Form c#

Tags: c#, html, winforms

Olá gostaria de pegar este valor, é uma class dentro da outra, estou tentando este código mais não retorna o valor.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = string.Empty;
        foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span"))

            if (el.GetAttribute("classname") == "point")
            {
                lb_show.Text = el.InnerText;
                //ou
                //lb_show.Text = el.InnerHTML;
            }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: mais o problema não é o mesmo @bigown, eu tenho que abrir duas class